# Shortest distance through columns in an array with costs?

Tags: c

```
  int a[5][5] = {
     //col 0 1 2 3 4

row   - 0 {0,0,0,0,0},
row   - 1 {5,0,0,0,0},
row   - 2 {0,0,0,0,6},
row   - 3 {0,0,0,0,5},
row   - 4 {0,5,0,0,0}};
```

I've been reading up on dijkstras algorithm and DFS but I don't understand if they even apply to what I'm trying to do.

Simply put I'm trying to put a program that gets you from column 0 to column 3, and in this case, if the col value is 0 you can't do anything but if the column value is >0 then you can jump to the col of that row.

Better put,

```
Col 0 = 
0
5
0
0
0
```

And we see that row index 1 has a value >0 so now we can jump to column 1
and from column 1, row index 4 > 0 so we then jump to column 4 and repeat etc.

Now here is the special part

```
Col 4 =
0
0
6
5
0
```

The 6 at row 2 will lead us to col 2 and the 5 at row 3 will lead us to col 3 which is where we want to end up.

So the shortest cost from col 0 to col 3 would be 5 + 5 + 5 = 15

How would I go about getting this, and say printing the path?

EDIT: Since col 2 is all zeros that would be a failed route and the program would go back and test the next available row from col 4

Comment: @4386427 sorry meant to add the case at the end, since this would be recursion based that recursive case would end and it would try the next element in col 4

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are doing. You say that the 5 in column 0 moves you to column 1. And that the 5 in column 1 moves you to column 4. How does that work?

Comment: @4386427 simply think of a double recursion, recursion one will loop through col 0 down to the bottom row looking for a # > 0, since row 1 at col 0 > 0, it will then pass that row value as a column value, so row 1 is passed and used as column one for the second recursive case, and rinse and repeat

Comment: So it is the **row index** of a `>0` element which determines the next **column index**

Comment: @4386427 exactly, and fixed the errors in my prompt